# android: my ListAdapter duplicates loop

Tags: android, listadapter

In my onCreate method of my Activity:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
registerForContextMenu(listView);
listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
Log.i(TAG, "list.size()" + list.size());
listView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, list));
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView.setClickable(true);
```

MyListAdapter:

```
    public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final String TAG = "MyListAdapter";
        private Activity context;

protected LayoutInflater mInflater;
    protected List<?> itemList;

        public MyListAdapter(Activity context, List<Event> list) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        itemList = list;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //DO Operations...

            Event item = (Event)(itemList.get(position));
            Log.i(TAG, "item.getName(): " + item.getName());


            return convertView;
        }


        public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    }
```

If I have 2 items in the list (A and B) I'll have this result in the logcat:

```
item.getName(): A
item.getName(): B
item.getName(): A
item.getName(): B
item.getName(): A
item.getName(): B
```

however, the items are correctly displayed on the listView, without duplications.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view if convertView is null (in getView()).
Other than that, I would not worry about it.

Comment: convertView is never null, I double-checked. My problem is that I have some logic in getView that gets duplicated...